# Beamer table of contents -- customize with block environments

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am trying to create a custom table of contents format. What I want to do is to have the description of the section inside a block environment like:

```
\section{Section 1}
\frame{
\begin{block}
This is section description 1
\end{block}
}

\section{Section 2}
\frame{
\begin{block}
This is section description 2
\end{block}
}

\section{Section 3}
\frame{
\begin{block}
This is section description 3
\end{block}
}
```

and then show those blocks in the table of contents, instead of the section names.

Let me explain why I need this. In my presentation I have three research questions that guide the overall presentation, and split it to several sections (each question is one section). Initially, I present all three together in one slide, but I then want to present only one of them, basically shading the rest, like what happens in the table of contents.

Is something like that possible?

Thanks in advance,
Y.K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below there's one possible solution; the basic idea is to redefine the `section in toc` template in such a way that the mandatory argument of `\section` will now be used for the description of the section and will be placed inside a block in the ToCs; the optional argument of `\section` can be used for the headline (in case an outer theme with section in the headline is being used). Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[breaklinks]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginSection{%
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\protect\block{Research Question~\inserttocsectionnumber}\inserttocsection\protect\endblock}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{General Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[Section one title]{This is section description 1}
\begin{frame}
Contents of section one
\end{frame}

\section[Section two title]{This is a very long section description. This is a very long section description. This is a very long section description. This is a very long section description.}
\begin{frame}
Contents of section two
\end{frame}

\section[Section three title]{This is section description 3}
\begin{frame}
Contents of section three
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and some of the resulting frames showing the two first partial ToCs with the descriptions inside a block (current section with normal code and other section shaded as requested) and the headline with the titles:

[image]

[image]

Comment: First, thanks for the quick reply. This is a step towards the right direction, but I would still like to maintain the original block environment (blue rounded box etc). Furthermore, I would like no enumeration, but this is a secondary concern. I would be glad to provide you with any additional info you may require.

Comment: @Y.K. Do you mean you want to include the complete blocks in the table of contents?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. I have added some description about why I want to do that in my original post. Maybe this helps clarify a few things... :) Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Y.K. I've updated my answer. It is something like that what you want?

Comment: Well... it's closer to what I had in mind. There are three problems with it :). First, I don't really want this "Section *" to be in the outline. Second, I want only the block of the current section to appear bold, the rest shaded (as I added to the original post). Finally, I don't want the blocks to appear before each section as well, as they do now. Are there any hope for those fixes? :)

Comment: @Y.K. sure there's hope ;-) However, with those requirements, it seems that you don't need a modification to the ToC. If you don't want any link to the sections (that was the role of the "Section #" line in my code) and you don't want the blocks to appear in any other place, then it seems to me that the only thing you need is a simple frame with the blocks: `\begin{frame}\frametitle{Outline}\begin{block}{}Description 1\end{block}\begin{block}{}Description 2\end{block}\begin{block}{}Description 3\end{block}\end{frame}`. Are you sure you need to modify the ToC or a simple frame would be enough?

Comment: Well... You are right half right :). I don't want any links, and I want the same frame to appear basically three times. However, in each of them I want only 1 block to be visible easily, and the other shaded. My first though was that this is what the TOC does (highlights the current section, shades all others), that's why I started experimenting with the TOC. If there is any other solutions that will basically allow me to select the block I want to be highlighted and shade the rest, then I am all ears :)

Comment: @Y.K. ah, I forgot about the shaded/non-shaded distinction. In this case, yes, it seems that the modification to the ToC is the way to go. Give me some minutes to produce some code ;-)

Comment: @Y.K. I updated my solution. I hope the new code is (almost) what you wanted ;-)

Comment: Hey! I posted 2 questions before, but I was able to fix them myself (the first about line break, the second about block title). Thank you so much for your help... I am excited with this outline now :) I edited your post (I hope you don't mind) with my changes and the breaklines argument, so that others can help themselves. Thanks again, you are great!

Comment: @Y.K. You're welcome! I didn't see the questions but I am glad to hear that you could answer them (I don't see any edits). Don't forget to accept the answer (by clicking on the check-mark to the left).

Comment: @Y.K. I now I see that some other user rejected your edit (he thought "it changed too much the original post and that the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost"). I personally don't agree with him, so I will incorporate your changes into my answer.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks a lot. I believe I accepted the answer (this is my first such attempt ever in stackexchange sites, so please check). I am surprised the other user stated this, since my changes were only of minor importance... anyway, thanks again for your help!:-)

Comment: @Y.K. Yes, you have accepted it. Thank you very much :-)